# Regex with chinese and english unicode

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, ecmascript-6

I am trying to detect hashtags  with some Chinese characters in the content given as follows:

```
#xyz Wo hat man die beste Aussicht auf die F1 Rennbahn? Kai Ebel hat 
einen Tipp für euch ! #visitsingaporeFür den Überblick: #ViewFromTheTop
Einer der besten Orte in Singapur , um das Nachtrennen von oben zu sehen
, ist für mich CE LA VI auf dem Marina Bay Sands. #wea周有七天 Die #kkk.
Panorma Sicht auf die Stadt und auf die Rennbahn sind spektakulär !
#visitsingapore https://s.l/JA5DAF #abc #周有七天 #a七
```

The regex that I tried was:

```
#[\u4E00-\u9FCC]+|#(\w)
```

but is unable to detect the complete hashtag like `#wea周有七天` How could I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Something like the following ?

```js
var string = '#xyz Wo hat man die beste Aussicht auf die F1 Rennbahn? Kai Ebel hat einen Tipp für euch ! #visitsingaporeFür den Überblick: #ViewFromTheTopEiner der besten Orte in Singapur , um das Nachtrennen von oben zu sehen, ist für mich CE LA VI auf dem Marina Bay Sands. Die #kkk. Panorma Sicht auf die Stadt und auf die Rennbahn sind spektakulär ! #visitsingapore https://s.l/JA5DAF #abc #周有七天 #a七 #wea周有七天';

const REGEX = /(#[\u4E00-\u9FCC]+|#(\w)\p{Script=Hani}.+|#(\w)+)/gu;
console.log(string.match(REGEX));
```

To match Chinese, you just do this:

```js
const REGEX = /(\p{Script=Hani})+/gu;
console.log('你好'.match(REGEX));
```

The trick is to use \p and use the right script name, Hani stands for Han script (Chinese). The full list of scripts is here: http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/PropertyValueAliases.txt

Comment: Good job ;) beat me 1seconde

Comment: Note that unicode properties are ES2018 and not universally supported yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to match all hashtags containing mixed chinese (in range `[\u4E00-\u9FCC]`and non-chinese characters  you could use

```
#[^\s]*[\u4E00-\u9FCC]+[^\s]*
```

Explanation: match 0 or more non-whitespace and at least one character in the range `[\u4E00-\u9FCC]`.

```js
txt = "#xyz Wo hat man die beste Aussicht auf die F1 Rennbahn? Kai Ebel hat einen Tipp für euch ! #visitsingaporeFür den Überblick: #ViewFromTheTop Einer der besten Orte in Singapur , um das Nachtrennen von oben zu sehen, ist für mich CE LA VI auf dem Marina Bay Sands. #wea周有七天 Die #kkk. Panorma Sicht auf die Stadt und auf die Rennbahn sind spektakulär ! #visitsingapore https://s.l/JA5DAF #abc #周有七天 #a七";

console.log(txt.match(/#[^\s]*[\u4E00-\u9FCC]+[^\s]*/gu));
```